# You have a Red Hat Nginx image, but when reloading the page you get a 404 error?

Tags: angular, docker, nginx, redhat

Currently, I am using in Dockerfile in my angular application, the configuration to use Nginx from Red Hat which is as follows:

```
FROM registry.access.redhat.com/ubi9/nginx-120:1-101
ADD  nginx-cfg/default.conf "${NGINX_CONFIGURATION_PATH}"
ADD  dist/generacionMasivaExtracto .
CMD nginx -g "daemon off;"
```

I do not know if I am taking correctly the configuration in my application, because when I refresh the browser I get a 404 Not Found error, normally I should not get this error when it is configured correctly.
this is the configuration of my Red Hat Nginx Server

```
server {
    listen       8083;
    server_name  prueba;
location /{
       root         /opt/app-root/src;
    index        index.html;
}
}
```

refreshing the page
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BdKsX.png)

without refreshing the page
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DNNXm.png)

this is the page where I am obtaining the image
[Nginx 1.20](https://catalog.redhat.com/software/containers/ubi9/nginx-120/61a609f2bfd4a5234d596287)

examples that have
[examples](https://github.com/sclorg/nginx-container/tree/master/examples/1.20/test-app)

Comment: Please translate your question title in English.

Comment: Hi, please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/7353417)